# PayPal API for “not-merchant”/private account

Tags: api, paypal

I start up my business so not have documents for business so I create an account personal on Paypal

so can using API or not for a private account can or not?

and I need to create something if client paid by PayPal credit card or Paypal account can't make refund again without my permission

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to a PayPal Business account.

If you're able to obtain the necessary API credentials via https://www.payapl.com/api , you might be able to receive API-based payments with the account as it currently.

Exact specifics and potential issues can depend on your location and integration method, however--so again, you should upgrade to a PayPal Business account.

Comment: okay but PayPal business needed documents paper for my company and i don't have this because I'm individual so what can i do ?

Comment: I don't know what documents those would be, since anyone can create a Business account. Contact PayPal if you need assistance.